# DownloadRangeToByteArrayAsync in .NET Core 2.0 Multithreading/Async Issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I'm encountering an issue with the DownloadRangeToByteArrayAsync Method in the Microsoft.AzureStorage 9.1 Nuget package on .NET Core 2.0. Whenever I perform DownloadRangeToByteArrayAsync either in Parallel or with async, it causes performance issues with any subsequent time-consuming operation. This was the code I used:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("<access_string>");
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("<container_name>");
        List<CloudBlockBlob> listBlobs = new List<CloudBlockBlob>();
        for (int c = 0; c < 100; c++)
        {
            listBlobs.Add(container.GetBlockBlobReference("<file_name>"));
        }

        var tasks = listBlobs.Select(async bl =>
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
            await bl.DownloadRangeToByteArrayAsync(buffer, 0, 65536, 128);
            return buffer;
        });
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        for (int c = 0; c < 100; c++)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            listBlobs[0].DownloadRangeToByteArrayAsync(buffer, 0, 65536 * c, 1024).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

When I executed the above code, after Task.WaitAll(), each iteration of the following loop was taking a long time. It took over 4x the time per iteration compared to if I did not include the Task.WaitAll in my code. It also took 4x the time as the exact same code executed in .NET Framework 4.6.1 (also with WindowsAzure.Storage 9.1.0). Replacing the Select statement with a Parallel.ForEach also caused the same issue, though if I did .Wait() instead of await on DownloadRangeToByteArrayAsync it was fine. Also past approximately 2 minutes of the LINQ/Parallel statement, the run-time of all subsequent operations went back to normal. In addition, when I debugged it, it showed that the LINQ statement (or the Parallel.ForEach) was creating over 100 threads on .NET Core, while it was only creating around 10 on .NET Framework. In addition, most of these 100+ threads didn't disappear at all, even after over an hour.

Does anyone have an idea what about DownloadRangeToByteArrayAsync or threading changed from .NET Framework 4.6.1 to .NET Core 2.0 that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this as well with concurrent asynchronous active directory calls. I think the red flag is that .Net Core generates so many parallel threads, 100 vs 10. To resolve my issue I limited the amount of parallelism allowed.

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    listBlobs,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 },
    listBlob => { 
        // Do stuff
    }
);
```

Comment: Tried using smaller numbers, it definitely lowered the number of threads but there were still some garbage threads being created, even increasing MaxDegreeofParallelism to 3 was causing some quite significant performance issues